How do I run thenSelenium scraper faster?
I need to scrap data instantly (5-10 sec), but my code works 60-80 sec.
if I a have better and faster idea, please let me know. It does not matter whether by the Selenium or even another language.
Here is my code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time

start = time.time()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/")
# Scrape the data
events = []

# Locate the rows in the table
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/section/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[14]')

for row in rows:
    try:
        actual = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[5]').text
        previous = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[7]').text

        events.append([actual, previous])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing row: {e}")

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(events, columns=[ 'Actual', 'Previous'])

df.head()

df.to_csv('economic_calendar.csv', index=False)

end = time.time()

print(end - start)


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It's scrape not scrap.

To get the data fast don't use selenium, try beautifulsoup instead:
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
table = soup.select_one("#economicCalendarData")

day = soup.select_one(".theDay").text

all_data = []
for row in table.select("tbody tr"):
    tds = row.select("td")
    if len(tds) != 8:
        continue
    all_data.append(
        {
            "Day": day,
            "Time": tds[0].get_text(strip=True),
            "Cur": tds[1].get_text(strip=True),
            "Imp.": "*" * len(tds[2].select(".grayFullBullishIcon")),
            "Event": tds[3].get_text(strip=True),
            "Actual": tds[4].get_text(strip=True),
            "Forecast": tds[5].get_text(strip=True),
            "Previous": tds[6].get_text(strip=True),
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)

Prints:
                      Day   Time  Cur Imp.                                       Event   Actual Forecast Previous
0   Tuesday, July 9, 2024  02:00  JPY    *                   Machine Tool Orders (YoY)     9.7%              4.2%
1   Tuesday, July 9, 2024  04:20  EUR   **                 German Buba Mauderer Speaks                           
2   Tuesday, July 9, 2024  05:40  EUR    *              Spanish 3-Month Letras Auction   3.293%            3.374%
3   Tuesday, July 9, 2024  06:00  USD    *          NFIB Small Business Optimism (Jun)     91.5     90.3     90.5
4   Tuesday, July 9, 2024  06:00  EUR   **                          Eurogroup Meetings                           
5   Tuesday, July 9, 2024  07:00  GBP    *                      BoE Quarterly Bulletin                           
6   Tuesday, July 9, 2024  08:55  USD    *                               Redbook (YoY)     6.3%              5.8%
7   Tuesday, July 9, 2024  09:15  USD   **  Fed Vice Chair for Supervision Barr Speaks                           
8   Tuesday, July 9, 2024  10:00  USD  ***                  Fed Chair Powell Testifies                           
9   Tuesday, July 9, 2024  10:00  USD   **            Treasury Secretary Yellen Speaks                           
10  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  11:30  USD    *                        52-Week Bill Auction   4.775%            4.915%
11  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  12:00  USD   **               EIA Short-Term Energy Outlook                           
12  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  13:00  USD   **                         3-Year Note Auction   4.399%            4.659%
13  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  13:30  USD   **                   FOMC Member Bowman Speaks                           
14  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  16:30  USD   **                  API Weekly Crude Oil Stock  -1.923M  -0.250M  -9.163M
15  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  18:45  NZD    *         External Migration & Visitors (May)   12.10%             1.70%
16  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  18:45  NZD    *         Permanent/Long-Term Migration (May)    1,410             5,110
17  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  18:45  NZD    *                Visitor Arrivals (MoM) (May)     4.0%             -9.4%
18  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  19:00  KRW    *                     Unemployment Rate (Jun)     2.8%              2.8%
19  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  19:50  JPY    *                             PPI (MoM) (Jun)     0.2%     0.4%     0.7%
20  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  19:50  JPY    *                             PPI (YoY) (Jun)     2.9%     2.9%     2.6%
21  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  21:30  AUD   **              Building Approvals (MoM) (May)              5.5%    -0.3%
22  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  21:30  AUD    *               Private House Approvals (May)              2.1%    -1.6%
23  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  21:30  CNY   **                             CPI (YoY) (Jun)              0.4%     0.3%
24  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  21:30  CNY   **                             CPI (MoM) (Jun)             -0.1%    -0.1%
25  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  21:30  CNY   **                             PPI (YoY) (Jun)             -0.8%    -1.4%
26  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  22:00  NZD  ***                 RBNZ Interest Rate Decision             5.50%    5.50%
27  Tuesday, July 9, 2024  22:00  NZD   **                         RBNZ Rate Statement                           

